# Knockout JS and observable radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am making a little app that will ask for a users location store that until a radio button is clicked, then call the google maps api to list places of the checked radio button nearby.

So far I have global a global object `var food = {
  mexican: "mexican food",
  pizza: "italian food",
  coffee: {
    venue: "cafe",
    keyword: "coffee"
  }
};`

to help me pass to a global variable `var queryL;` that is in the api call.

```
var viewModel = function() {
  food: ko.observable
```

now I got this far and need a bit of assistance figuring out the three radio buttons and changing the values.

in pseudo code something like:

```
    if (mexican is checked) {  
     queryL = food.mexican;
     initmap();
} else if (pizza is checked) {
     queryL = food.pizza;
     initmap();
} else if (coffee is checked) {
     queryL = food.coffee.keyword;
     typeL = food.coffee.venue;
     initmap();
}
```

How would I accomplish this?

```
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="mexican" data-bind="checked: typeOfFood">Tacos</input></label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="pizza" data-bind="checked: typeOfFood">Pizza</input></label>
<label class="radio-inline"><input type="radio" name="optradio" value="coffee" data-bind="checked: typeOfFood">Coffee</input></label>
```

radio buttons ^^

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can subscribe to your `typeOfFood` observable and have your logic inside subscribe call back function.

Here is an example: https://jsfiddle.net/kyr6w2x3/98/

```
var viewModel = function (){
 var self = this;
 self.food = ko.observable(food);
 self.queryL = ko.observable('');
 self.typeL  = ko.observable('');
 self.typeOfFood = ko.observable();

 self.typeOfFood.subscribe(function(newValue){
    switch(newValue){
      case "mexican":
      //do your stuff here
      self.queryL(self.food().mexican);
      self.initMap();
      break;
    case "pizza":
      //do your stuff here
      self.queryL(self.food().pizza);
      self.initMap();
      break;
    case "coffee":
      //do your stuff here
      self.queryL(self.food().coffee.keyword);
      self.typeL(self.food().coffee.venue);
      self.initMap();
      break;
    }
  })

 self.initMap = function(){
   // your initMap Function here
   console.log("inside initMap function");
   console.log("queryL: " , self.queryL());
   console.log("typeL: " , self.typeL());
 }
}
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```